# Copy xfce4 configuration files from one user to another

Tags: 14.04, xfce

Well, it seems easy but I can't get it.

I've created a template user wich I use to create or update another users configuration.

To update configuration from the user template to another user I run:

```
sudo cp -r --preserve /home/template/.config /home/user1/.config      
sudo chown -R user1:users /home/user1/.config
```

I don't see any errors. But when I log in with user1 I realize than XFCE desktop configuration has not changed, I mean, it has not been updated with template configuration. I particular, I note than any changes on desktop configuration are ignored.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the error, it was so obvious but I didn't see it.

When I run

```
sudo cp -r --preserve /home/template/.config /home/user1/.config
```

the effect is that it creates a new directory .config **inside** /home/user1/.config.

The right script would be:

```
sudo cp -r --preserve /home/template/.config /home/user1/
```

Answer (score 2):

In some cases (maybe even always) after quitting xfce4 session `xfconfd` daemon is still running. You need to log in under `user1` to plain terminal session and `pkill xfconfd`. Then if you'll start xfce4 session you'll see that new xfce4 settings are applied.

Answer (score 0):

To be thorough, when you login as "template" everything looks good? And "template"'s home is in `/home/template`?

When I backup my XFCE home config files (I think they're all in ~/.config, just a few app specific ones in .local or .gconf) and a `.gtkrc-xfce` file that appears to only be "XfdesktopIconView" desktop settings, probably not critical but...

And it doesn't always work unless I'm logged out of the user being backed up.

I use a plain `tar -cf`, but cp should work.

And you're changing the owner to the new user, that must be them in the `$1` in your chown? I don't know if the group would matter, but according to `chown` if you just used `chown -R user: [files]` that means:

> "If a colon but no group name follows the
>   user  name, that user is made the owner of the files and the group of the files
>   is changed to that user's login group."

The same permissions are on the new files as the old ones?

---

Here's what I've ran to backup XFCE user settings before:

```
sudo tar --xz --one-file-system -cvf /tmp/userHome-bak.tar.xz -C /home/user/ --files-from=/home/add.txt
```

And in add.txt (one per line, definitely DON'T need them all, some may be holdovers from older DE's too): `.config` `.gconf` `.gnome2` `.gnome2_private` `.linuxmint` `.local` `.bashrc` `.gtk-bookmarks` `.gtkrc-xfce` `.ICEauthority` `.xscreensaver`

Then after restoring to newuser's home, to make sure: `chown -R newuser /home/newuser`

Comment: When I login as "template" everything looks good, and "template"'s home is in /home/template.

Comment: I've replaced $1 with user1. The original script uses $1, but I'v simplified it for this post.

Comment: Something might not be getting set as the right user, or missing a config file somehow. I'll edit with some backup files that work for me. But exactly what "changes on desktop configuration are ignored"? When you're logged in as template, change things, then copy to the new user something doesn't change?

Comment: I've tried copying .local and .gconf, but it doesn't work. Do you know what file is stored the desktop configuration in?

Comment: `/home/user/.config/xfce4/` has all the XFCE stuff I know of. If you're getting all of `.config` then it should be in there too

Comment: In particular, I notice that when I change the desktop color in the "template" and I update "user1", the desktop color in "user1" doesn't change.

Comment: I think I've found the error. When I run cp it doesn't copy changes made on source. Do you understand why?

Comment: Unless you've got `--no-clobber` by default with sudo, or might need `-f` or `--remove-destination`. It should be copying the files, changed or not.